# How to modify desktop calendar settings on Kubuntu 14.04?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, thunderbird, calendar

How can I modify the following things on the desktop calendar on Kubuntu 14.04 with kde 4.13:

1.change the first day of the week to monday

2.remove these useless US holidays from it

3.there are different colors with different special days how can I modify the colors

4.can I somehow link this desktop calendar to thunderbird to have the same entries in both?

thx in advance

cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 and 2. SystemSetting -> Locale -> Calendar
3. Not easily. You can change the whole color scheme item by item in SystemSettings -> Application Appearance -> Color
4. That depends on the level of integration that you want. The KDE calendar is based on KOrganizer, which can use several types of calendars. You can find a type of calendar that can be used by both Thunderbird and KOrganizer (e.g. iCal) to have them in sync.

Comment: thx I gonna check these then more deeply :D